# Working with classes in PHP (PHP Version 5.4.9)

Tags: php, dto

I have a class as follows

```
class DatabaseConnectionDTO {
    private $databaseServerName;

        public function set($dbServerName){
            $this->databaseServerName = $dbServerName;
        }

        public function get() {
            return $this->databaseServerName;
        }
    }
```

This class is inside a DTO folder under the main project root folder. Under the project root folder I have another PHP file that is calling this class.

The file under the root folder :

```
require('./DTO/DatabaseConnectionDTO.php');
$databaseDTO = new DatabaseConnectionDTO;
$databaseDTO->set('Blaise Pascal');
echo $databaseDTO -> get();
```

My idea is to set the value of the property and display it on the page. However when I access the page on my browser I get the following

```
        databaseServerName = $dbServerName;
    }
    public function get() {
        return $this->databaseServerName;
    }
}
?>
```

Is there something that I am missing here?

**EDIT**
When I place the DTO inside the same PHP file it starts working.. but that is not how I want it .. I want each and every DTO to be in a specific location.

**Edit 2**
Adding some snapshots

[image]

[image]

Comment: tip- whenever working with php/html, always right click -> view source in the browser.

Comment: Sounds like your server is not configured to handle PHP files

Comment: Does your class file have an opening `<?php`? Without it, the code would be sent straight to the output stream.

Comment: @micheal - Yes my class has opening and closing PHP tags..

Comment: @Gagan Then view the source as suggested. The web server may not be processing PHP at all.  This is running from a server, right? And not just from a locally opened file?

Comment: @SimpleCoder Other simple PHP pages work fine ( for example I am connecting to the database directly ) and that is working..

Comment: The other strange this - I have the same code in PHPstorm and its giving me the correct results when I debug my code through it ..

Comment: Whatever is inside `./DTO/DatabaseConnectionDTO.php` obviously has no `<?php` at the top.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You have `<? php`.

You need to have `<?php`.